# Estimating length of skeletonized features

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I've been trying for some time now to extract information from some data collected, namely the length of the features seen in the bottom left figure. In the bottom right I've skeletonized my features - can someone suggest a strategy to "count" the number of pixels each connected segment?

*Unfortunately, although a skeleton is a nice estimation of the medial axis of my features, it can't be detected by methods such as detectContours. I have also tried fitting straight line segments to contours detected in the raw image (left), but a polynomial fit is better.

[image][image]

Comment: I think you can use `findNonZero()` to count white pixels (if your components are black, reverse the image and then count the whites). And, I don't see the need for skeletonization...

Comment: How do you mean? I would like to estimate the length along the medial axis of each individual component, not the sum all all non-white features.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest algorithm for connected component labeling seems to be the Union-Find algorithm. [Here is a code](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d480842/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/java-etiquettage-composantes-connexes-union-find/) (Java first post, and C in the second).

But I am surprised that such a method does not exist in OpenCV.

For the medial axis, you should take a look to the Voltige library, written by Eric Remy (medial axis specialist).